# Postgres database randomly reverted, am I handling my database connection properly?

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using Python SQLAlchemy 1.4.xx to write changes to a database and last night I lost about 12 million rows across different tables, which hurts my soul. Before this morning I could access, manipulate, read, write, and other normal db operations of the data,but now it seems that the database reverted to a state from about a month ago. The even weirder part is that I didn't have a backup saved for the date that the db seems to have reverted to. I only have a backup of the db saved from the day prior. So it leads me to believe 2 things:

1. That a command was not run to explicitly revert or rollback the db.
2. Maybe I have messed up how I save data into the database.

For saving Data into my database I use the following code:

```
class Database:
    
    def __init__(self, database_params=None):
        if database_params is None:
            database_params = DATABASE_PARAMS
        self.database_params = database_params

        # dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
        self.engine = db.create_engine(
            f"{self.database_params['engine']}://{self.database_params['user']}:{quote(self.database_params['password'])}@{self.database_params['host']}:{self.database_params['port']}/{self.database_params['database_name']}"
        )
        self.connection = None

    def start_connection(self):
        """
        Helper function to resume a connection from the connection pool
        :return:
        """
        if self.connection is None:
            self.connection = self.engine.connect()

    def end_connection(self):
        """
        Helper function to give a connection back to the connection pool
        :return:
        """
        if self.connection is not None:
            self.connection.close()
            self.connection = None

    def restart_connection(self):
        """
        Helper function to restart a connection
        :return:
        """
        self.end_connection()
        self.start_connection()

    def execute_wrapper(self, qstring, vars_obj=None, fetchall=False, fetchone=False):
        """
        :param qstring:
        :param vars_obj:
        :param fetchall:
        :param fetchone:
        :return:
        """
        if self.connection is None:
            # start a connection
            self.start_connection()
        while True:
            try:
                if vars_obj is None:
                    res = self.connection.execute(qstring)
                else:
                    if isinstance(vars_obj, list):
                        res = self.connection.execute(qstring, vars_obj)
                        self.connection.commit()
                    else:
                        res = self.connection.execute(qstring, vars_obj)
                break
            except (
                sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError,
                psycopg2.OperationalError,
                sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError,
            ) as e:
                # database may be resetting or disconnected try again in a minute
                database_logger.error(
                    f"Database seems to be offline, retrying again in 60 seconds"
                )
                print("errored with", e)
                time.sleep(60)
                self.restart_connection()
            except Exception as e:
                database_logger.critical(
                    f"Unknown Database Error: {e}\nError Type: {type(e)}\nQuery String: {qstring}"
                )
                print("errored with", e)
                time.sleep(60)
                self.restart_connection()

        if fetchall is True:
            res = res.fetchall()
        elif fetchone is True:
            res = res.fetchone()
        return res
```

**Overarching Question:** Am I handling my database connection improperly for updating and querying data from the db?

Comment: I am only seeing `self.connection.commit()` being called in one branch of your conditional logic. Without a `commit` data changes will not survive a session. So no I don't think you are handling your connection correctly.

Comment: An open-for-weeks transaction would mean backups wouldn't see your changes either, which fits.

Comment: The reason I call self.connection.commit() only on that specific branch is (as I understand it) because the `engine.connect()` returns a connection object that auto commits except in specific instances which is caught by that branch. Auto committing will be removed in 2.xxfrom whatIunderstand though

Comment: turns out it was an issue with how I was setting up the docker container

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the container that everything was hosted in was the cause of the issue. In `/etc/fstab/` the line that mounted the db had the flag `nofail` which was removed and everything worked. Sorry if that isn't helpful to whoever finds this.